# Calling a function from 'text' in swift

Tags: swift, alert, generics

I'm writing some generic code, so all view controllers can use it.
One of the things I like to make generic is an alert function.
The problem here is that I must code the actions in the replies.
That's fine with warnings (only press OK), or generic responses (Cancel, No), but when a (generic) function needs to run, I need to trick to pass on which function.
If I can run a function from some text, it will reduce the problem (and I don't have to hard-code all the functions that can be called).
Or is there a much better way of achieving my 'generic' alert?

Sample here:

```
func DoAlert(title: String, message: String, actions: String, sender: AnyObject, viewController : UIViewController) {.......
.....
if (actions as NSString).containsString("Yes") {
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
    if (actions as NSString).containsString("Yes'DoAfunction()'") {
        DoAfunction() }
    })} 
.....
}
```

// Rather than hard-coding, I like to abstract the function between ' ' and use that to call the function

// I call the function as follows:

```
DoAlert("Warning", alertText, "Yes'DoAfunction()'No", sender, self)
```

///////////      SOLUTION:     ////////////////

Following Bluehound's suggestion to use closures, I ended up adding optional closures for different responses.

For those wishing to do same, below is my solution:

**Solution here:**

```
func DoAlert(title: String, message: String, actions: String, sender: AnyObject, viewController : UIViewController, YesClosure: ()->() = {}, NoClosure: ()->() = {}) {.......
.....
if (actions as NSString).containsString("Yes") {
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { action -> Void in

    YesClosure()   // This will the run the function if provided

    })} 
.....
}
```

// I call the function as follows:

```
    DoAlert("Warning", alertText, "YesNo", sender, self, YesClosure: DoYesFunction, NoClosure: DoNoFunction)
```

If there is nu function to be performed, leave the option out. (below only has function for NO)

```
    DoAlert("Warning", alertText, "YesNo", sender, self, NoClosure: DoNoFunction)
```

Comment: You could pass a closure as an argument and in the closure call the function

Comment: I'm quite new to Swift, so can you explain, or have sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the name of a function to complete, you can pass a closure as a parameter and when calling the function, you define what goes function is passed in. For example:

```
func foo(closure: () -> Void) {
    closure()
}

foo {
    println("Some text")
} // prints Some Text
```

Now for using multiple actions you can pass an array of closures like so:

```
func foo(closures: [() -> Void]) {
    for closure in closures {
        closure()
    }
}

foo([{println("a")},
    {println("b")},
    {println("c")}]) // prints a b c
```

Comment: Bluehound, You steered me in the correct direction.

Comment: Although not initially too clear, Found good samples in StackOverflow to use optional closures. I've added my solution in the original question area for those  interested.